# Emacs "jump to class definition" functionality?

Tags: terminal, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I want to jump to a class file "A" from another file "B" which defines objects "A". In eclipse, it is done using <kbd>F3</kbd>. Is there a way to achieve this in emacs?

Comment: Any particular programming language? Emacs language specific functions need to know how to look for a class definition (just like with emacs).

Comment: Anthon, I'm programming in java.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>, assuming you have the [Java Development Environment for Emacs](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) installed.

Comment: I'm unable to follow the installation instructions as http://jdee.sunsite.dk is down.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the eclim package which can do this and much more: http://www.skybert.net/emacs/java/